# Bash script error trying to write to file: no such file or directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, filenames, date, slash

I'm getting an error with a very simple script. The script should run pg_dumpall and write the output to a file but I'm getting an error that the resulting file doesn't exist. I know it doesn't exist, thats why I want to creat it! :-/

```
#!/bin/bash
#remove previous day's dump and create new
rm -f /home/user/db_dump_*.txt;
pg_dumpall -U postgres -w > /home/user/db_dump_`date '+%d/%m/%Y_%H:%M:%S'`.txt;
```

The result is:

```
db_dump.sh: line 4: /home/user/db_dump_12/02/2017_14:30:15.txt: No such file or directory
```

The date command is working fine and the filename comes out perfect but instead of the file being created, I get the error saying that it doesn't exist. I'm running the script as root so there should be no issues with permissions. I can write to the user's home directory without any problems.

Any ideas?

Comment: Since your filename contains slashes, try pre-creating the directories involved before trying to write to a file inside them. In this instance, `mkdir -p /home/user/db_dump_12/02`. On the other hand, I urge you to reconsider your directory structure as it doesn't seem logical to, say, keep all of the files written on the 12th of any month in a given directory. Perhaps if your date format were big-endian instead oflittle-endian it might make more sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that generated filename again:

```
/home/user/db_dump_12/02/2017_14:30:15.txt
```

It tries to write into a subdirectory called `02` of `db_dump_12`. If these directories don't exist, you'll get a "No such file or *directory*" error.

I suggest using another date format:

```
dumpfile_date=$( date +"%F-%T" ) # or %Y%m%d-%H%M%S or something similar
pg_dumpall -U postgres -w > "/home/user/db_dump_$dumpfile_date.txt"
```

Comment: derp... Yeah, that'll do it... Slashes in the date are gonna be read as a path...

Comment: I just replaced the slashes with hyphens in the date parameters and it works the way I want. Thanks!